# jQuery multiple scroll function header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

a update of the code what i got so far.
I got instead of the var search and request pixels, but i want var. That's better for the code and it's more accurate.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (document.getElementById("style-request")) {
    $(".search_bar_knop").hide();
    $(".submit-a-request").hide();

    $(window).scroll(function() {    

      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      var request = document.getElementsByClassName("submit-a-request");
      var search = document.getElementsByClassName("search_bar_knop");

      if (scroll >= search) {
        $(".search_bar_knop").show();
        document.getElementsByClassName('helpcenter')[0].style.visibility='hidden';
      }
      else {
        $('.search_bar_knop').hide();
        document.getElementsByClassName('helpcenter')[0].style.visibility='visible';
      }

      if (scroll >= request)  {
        $('.submit-a-request').show();
      } 
      else  {
        $('.submit-a-request').hide();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Hope you could help me out.

Comment: so you want `1` if above 500px, `2` if you are between 500 and 1000?

Comment: No the (two) has to be above 1000px

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Look at the demo i made. http://jsfiddle.net/51q2v6of/1/

Comment: I added some more info about the problem

Comment: could you provide source or the working code, before you added the extra button?

Comment: Thanks Starvator! I forgot to close the else if with a }. Thats why he didn't worked. Thanks you verry much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want, 
Here is your jQuery

```
$(function() {
    var header = $(".clearHeader");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 500 && scroll <= 1000) {
            header.removeClass('clearHeader extraHeader').addClass('darkHeader');
        } 
        else if (scroll >= 1000) {
            header.removeClass('darkHeader clearHeader').addClass('extraHeader');
        }
        else {
            header.removeClass('darkHeader extraHeader').addClass('clearHeader');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider the following header.removeClass('clearHeader extraHeader').addClass('darkHeader');